# Обработка нескольких checkbox с одним и тем же name

Tags: php, html

Доброго времени! У меня такая задача - на странице циклом php выводится в форме разное количество чекбоксов например так

```
<input type="checkbox" name="yap" value="12">
<input type="checkbox" name="yap" value="8">
<input type="checkbox" name="yap" value="44">
```

value - у них всегда разные и всегда цифры. Пользователь должен отметить один или сразу несколько может даже все и запустить отправку формы submit

но вот как мне поймать уже массив этих чекбоксов сколько значений пользователь отметил и какие значения были в отмеченных чекбоксах? в переменной $_POST['yap'] всегда остается значение последнего выведенного чекбокса. Подскажите как их ловить для обработки, или даже не через чек бокусы это делать? но напоминаю чек боксов может быть всегда произвольное количество от одного до к примеру 20ти и value всегда разые

Comment: Есть одна проблема в предложенном Вами варианте: в массиве yap будут присутствовать только выбранные чекбоксы.
Например, выбраны все, тогда:<br>
yap[0]=on<br>
yap[1]=on<br>
yap[2]=on<br>
Если выбрать первый и третий, то:<br>
yap[0]=on<br>
yap[1]=on<br>
Я нашел рекомендации обрабатывать значения чекбоксов с помощью скрытого поля формы, в котором, в зависимости от состояния чекбокса, значение или 0, или 1. Но здесь возникает проблема обработки значений чекбоксов при изменении их значения. По идее, это делется javascript'ом, но как передать в скрипт id конкретного чекбокса из цикла, даже при испо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Укажите имя с квадратными скобками yap[]

```
<input type="checkbox" name="yap[]" value="12">
<input type="checkbox" name="yap[]" value="8">
<input type="checkbox" name="yap[]" value="44">
```

тогда на сервере вы получите массив yap с выбранными значениями

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте к имени чекбоксов скобочки, чтобы получилось `yap[]` и обрабатывайте массив `$_POST['yap']`.